# Singapore timezone issue in PHP, SGT and +08:00 offer different answers

Tags: php, datetime, timezone, strtotime

```
echo date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime("2014-06-26 12:00:00 SGT"));
```

Returns `2014-06-26 06:30:00`

while

```
echo date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime("2014-06-26 12:00:00 +08:00"));
```

returns the correct answer - `2014-06-26 06:00:00`

on http://phpepl.cloudcontrolled.com/

Does any one have any idea why?

I am getting similar issues on my server which is converting to UTC, and using PHP 5.3.28

Comment: @1nflktd oh lols nice catch! Seems still broken as 1 year ago and 5.3.3 .. Any idea if its fixed in the later ones? How is this still not fixed!!!!! Do you want to put that as the answer? I will accept

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singapore_Standard_Time It appears that until 1981, SGT was +730, wonder if that is the issue.. if so.. how old is the bug :P

Comment: well its an oooold bug then :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a php bug that apparently persists since 2008 (!), when it was first related (probably its way older).

https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=45081

Answer (score 1):

A couple of things:

- Yes, 1nflktd's answer is correct (and should remain the accepted answer).  There is a bug in PHP.

  Well, it's not so much a "bug" as a design flaw.  When a time zone abbreviation is included in the string passed to `strtotime`, it is resolved via [a hardcoded list](https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/master/ext/date/lib/timezonemap.h). This is problematic, because [many time zone abbreviations are not unique](http://codeofmatt.com/2014/04/27/time-zone-abbreviations/), but also many have changed their definition over time.  The hardcoded offset may not be the correct one for the date in question.

  As Karthik pointed out in comments, SGT used to be at UTC+7:30 instead of it's current UTC+08:00.  This actually took place in 1982 - [as seen in the time zone data](https://github.com/eggert/tz/blob/2014e/asia#L2429-L2430).

  If possible, you should avoid passing time zone abbreviations to `strtotime`.
- I noticed that your results are off by two hours.  That's because the time zone on the PHP repl site you referenced is `Europe/Berlin`, which is at UTC+02:00 for the date in question.  So the `SGT` or `+08:00` is being applied, but then the answer is being converted to Berlin time.

  You should consider setting the local time zone using [`date_default_timezone_set`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date-default-timezone-set.php).
- If you are trying to convert to UTC (GMT), you can use `gmdate`, like this:

  ```
  date_default_timezone_set("Asia/Singapore");
  echo gmdate('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime("2014-06-26 12:00:00"));
  ```

  Outputs: `2014-06-26 04:00:00`, which is correct, since 4+8=12.

Comment: oh cool, didnt know abt `gmdate`. As for the php repl timezone, I understand that wasnt at UTC, thats y i specifically talk abt the 30 min difference, not the absolute offset itself.

Comment: It maybe a design flaw, but it is also a bug since now SGT is unambiguously +800....

Comment: HOLY CRAP ON A CRACKER.. just saw this :D :D " { "sgt", 0, 27000, "Asia/Singapore" },
{ "sgt", 0, 28800, "Asia/Singapore" }," Apparently singapore is on there twice!